# how can i pass variable in parameter as a function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

if i have this function:

```
   function test(x){  
   alert(x);
   }
```

when I run it as:

```
test('hello world');
```

i will get a window.

good, instead of passing a parameter as string.. 
i need pass a parameter as function, like that:

```
   function test(x){  
   x;
   }
```

then i run:

```
   test(alert('hello world'));
```

So how can I pass a function as a parameter to another function?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to have `x` actually be a function, and you have to actually call it:

```
function test(x) {
  x();
}

test(function() { alert("Hello World!"); });
```

By itself, `alert("Hello World!")` is just an expression, not a function. The only way to syntactically turn an expression into a function (without immediately evaluating it, at least) is with that function instantiation syntax above.

Comment: Also just a note: if you want to pass in a defined function.. `function derp() { alert("herp"); }` then you simply pass the *function reference* in as a parameter. `test(derp); //no ()!`

Comment: @SterlingArcher yes indeed, thanks for the observation!